# Images dont work with css

Tags: css, image

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but for some reason after 5 hours of work I'm stuck with nothing working...

I have a header which has a logo and the telephone (both of which are images).  I want the telephone to be at the middle right of header and then move to the left as the user resizes the window.  But when I tried, it moves down.  I'd like the logo to be positioned on top of ΛΟΓΙΣΜΙΚΟ and move with the menu (staying on top) as the user resizes.

Here is the site: http://www.altasoft.gr/index_.htm

Can this be done with JavaScript?

```
 <div class="header">
    <div style="position:relative; left:17%; top:10px; z-index:99;">
        <img  src="images/Altasoft_Logo.png" alt="" width="354" height="91" />
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative; left:80%; top:-30px; z-index:5;">
      <img src="images/telephone.gif" alt="" width="142" height="16" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Replace your table layout with divs. Then it will work with CSS.

Comment: It's hard to know how to get the functionality you want without seeing the markup for what you want it to be positioned with

Comment: Position them both from the right instead of left using a percentage based value.

Comment: thx all for answers i tried it with css and got some probems too il write the code soon

Comment: cant make it move with the menu.. when i change windows size Logo is not moving with the menu and its not staying on top of Λογισμικο..any ideas? thx!

Comment: You want to 'move' the image or make parts from within image move ? Here is your logo image : http://www.altasoft.gr/images/Altasoft_Logo.png . You want it to do what again ?

Comment: under the logo its the menus i want the logo to be in line with the Λογισμικο menu when i resize the window thx!

Comment: After so many days, did you solve your situation ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 931px; /* make this same width than 'main content'*/
  z-index: 10;
}
```

in your first divider, style it this way :

```
element.style {
/*  left: 17%; */ /* remove the left:17% */
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

It will align your header and menu

Comment: THx a lot!! by first divider you mean??

Comment: i need a style for the div with the logo and 1 with the telephone and i want the logo to move with the menus. should i put the same style at both divs? when i applied it at the logo it just moved at right edge of the screen and its not moving...

Comment: Your .header has to be set in width. By your first divider i meant <div class=header> <div is first>

Comment: and the element.style should go to logo?